# Is there any way to set the content type of JQuery's $.POST ajax shorthand call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jmeter

A page I built is currently undergoing jmeter testing, and the content type that JQuery's $.POST function uses by default (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) is causing problems.  I'd like to be able to set that content-type to text/plain.
I realize that this can be done by setting the contentType setting while using the $.ajax format, but there are a lot of places I would need to update the code, and since the page is already QA passed, this would cause more risk than I'd like.

So, is there any way for me to set the content-type using the $.POST?  Or some sort of workaround?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[jQuery.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)**

> Set default values for future Ajax requests.

---

All subsequent Ajax calls using any function will use the new settings, unless overridden by the individual calls, until the next invocation of `$.ajaxSetup()`.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    contentType: 'text/plain'
});
```

Now all future ajax calls will use this `contentType`

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
});
```

---

> and since the page is already QA passed, this would cause more risk than I'd like

You should still have QA retest this since it's a functional change and may cause errors. My $.02

Comment: Yeah, we're doing some regression testing, but this (I feel) is a much faster and less risky change, so thanks!